# Htaccess - Redirect same filename from a folder to main directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ftp

I have a website in which i had a /mobile/ folder with a content copy of the site but optimized for mobile. Inside that folder i had another two folders for english and german languages, while in the main folder i had the content in Spanish.

Lately, the desktop spanish version was changed to have a responsive design, so i need to redirect the files inside /mobile/ to the main directory (same filename as the one requested), but the content inside /mobile/de/ and /mobile/en/ should still be accessible.

This is the code i´ve come up with. For some reason it causes an internal server error:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^mobile/de - [L]
RewriteRule ^mobile/en - [L]
RewriteRule ^mobile/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `sudo a2enmod rewrite` ? Are these lines the only  ones in the htaccess file?

Comment: no, i have a lot more instructions, but before this i didn´t have that error

Comment: Is this at the top then? Could you show some more lines?

Comment: I´ve placed that part of code at the bottom. Do you think that it should help placing it at the bottom?

Comment: i think the placement does not matter. Tried placing it first and it generated a 500 internal server error

Comment: no, I mean it seems that they go at the top and so there are other lines that follow and it is somehow conflicting. Couldn't there be some unvisible symbol?

Comment: i tried on some other site with a fairly clean htaccess and it worked. Now i´m pretty sure it is having some trouble with something inside the htaccess. Thanks for the clue